# Excel Get Worksheet as Collection

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am new to RPA/Blue Prism.

I have a problem with the Action "Get Worksheet as Collection".
In the excel sheet are hidden columns and these are not found.

Blue Prism returns error message:

> Internal: Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Column 17 was not found.

I've already tried the other Get Worksheet * actions

How can I get Blue Prism to read the hidden columns or make it unhidden so that it can be read?

Comment: Are you able to change the Excel file? If so, simply provide file with all columns showed..

Comment: The excel-file is automatic generated by a system-tool. We dont habe the ability to change it... :( We have to take it as it comes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not the hidden lines. However, I have found the error it was the line breaks (char 10 +13). Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information?

i think you can unhide all column through this macro or use the robot to unhide them

```
`Sub UnhideAllColumns ()
Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False EndSub`
```

let me know if it helps out